# LINQ on BindingList

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `BindingList` I return from datacontext using Entity framework. I would like to use LINQ to get a subset of the data. How can I do that without converting to `ObservableCollection` or `List` because I don't want to lose the functionality exposed by `BindingList`?

```
BindingList<People> ppl = context.Peoples.Local.ToBindingList();
```

I'd Like to user `.Where(p=>p.Name.Contains("ab"))`
Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The `BindingList<T>` class has a constructor that accepts a `List<T>`:

```
BindingList<People> ppl = new BindingList<People>(context.Peoples.Local.Where(p => p.Name.Contains("ab")).ToList());
```